# MongoDB Permalink Schema Design / ExpressJS implementation for RESTful routing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am new to mongo, and application design in general, having simply used gems in the past to handle my permalinks (coming from a rails background). I was wondering how best to handle permalinks.

Should you have a collection in mongodb, that links permalinks to their object ids, or is it better to pretty much replace the object id with the permalink acting as the uid? Or should there be some kind of combination of both, where the permalink is simply used in the router and then ids are used in the application internally?

Also some advice on how best to implement these in the application itself as well as the db would be great, I am using expressjs if that's any help.

Thank you.